# MySQL returns a skipped row on order by with same date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL query that is like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM posts
ORDER BY createdAt DESC;
```

and returns with this:

[image]

The results are expected.

But when I add a `LIMIT and OFFSET` condition it skips rows.

Example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM posts
ORDER BY createdAt DESC
LIMIT  5
OFFSET 2;
```

Result:

[image]

---

My expectation is that it should return ids `20, 19, 18, 17, 13` instead it skipped some of the rows - why is that? I'm not sure if it's the date that throwing MySQL or it's because of my query.

Comment: can you try ordering by id and check if the result is as expected

Comment: @OMiShah It'll work but im not looking for the ID im looking for the latest created posts.

Comment: is ID set autoincrement? or value is manually assigned. even if you order by id DESC you will always get the latest posts first if ID value is not reused

Comment: @Strawberry What's not clear on my question? Why are you giving me this link?

Comment: @OMiShah yes ID has a constraint `PRIMARY  KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`. I get what you mean but that's crazy that I cant order by createdAt.

Comment: had the same problem! any luck?

Answer (score -1):

If some records have the same value for the expression used for sorting they are returned in random order. I.e. sorting within such group is non-deterministic.

The records 6-11 in your output (ids 13,16,15,14,12,11) have the same value in the field used for sorting. And these records sorting within this group is random, and it may change in any time - even at the next query execution.

When you use LIMIT only one of these 6 records matched the specified records numbers region. And this one record from all 6 possible is selected randomly. Today id=12 is selected, tomorrow it may be some another - non-deterministic again.

If you need deterministic sorting order, the records must be unique by sorting expression. Alter it, for example, to `ORDER BY createdAt DESC, id` - and your problem will disappear.

Comment: . . They are not returned in RANDOM order.  They are returned in an indeterminate order, and that ordering could change with each execution (or not).

Comment: @Akina thank you for the response but I think you are wrong. Last night I tested it by querying multiple times I got the same result over and over again.

Comment: @Akina eyy condolence my guy but its irrelevant.

Comment: @aRtoo If trouble can happen, it happens. Look [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fbdf3eae238d389d795c6dcc71ba9ff8) as a demo... the query is absolutely the same.